# Weird error: [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'count' must be non-negative

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, orm, dependency-injection, spring.net

I have a site which runs in ASP.NET 3.5, NHibernate 2.2 and Sprint .NET for Dependency Injection. On our test server a rather strange error occurrs, and also almost everytime there are multiple users online. After the problem has occurred, this error is displayed for every user and every request they make - until you do an IISRESET. Then it is all ok again.

Here's the exception:

```
'count' must be non-negative.
Parameter name: count 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'count' must be non-negative.
Parameter name: count

Source Error: 
[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET      Files\root\4bf9aa39\6dcf5fc6\App_Web_z9ifuy6t.6.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'count' must be non-negative.
Parameter name: count]
System.String.CtorCharCount(Char c, Int32 count) +10082288
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(String name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean suppressConfigure) +3612
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObject(String name) +75
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.GetObjectsOfType(Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects) +365
Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.GetObjectsOfType(Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects) +136
Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.GetObjectsOfType(Type type) +66


[ActivationException: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type InfoTextService, key ""]
   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in      c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:57
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance() in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:90
OurProjectsNamespace.Infrastructure.ObjectLocator.LocateService() +86
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a very wierd error. When you look at the source of the `AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal` you will see the following structure:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private int nestingCount;

protected object GetObjectInternal(...)
{
    const int INDENT = 3;
    bool hasErrors = false;
    try
    {
        nestingCount++;

        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            log.Debug("msg" + 
                new String(' ', nestingCount * INDENT));
        }

        // More code: Calls self recursively.
    }
    catch
    {
        nestingCount--;
        hasErrors = true;

        if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
        {
            log.Error("msg" + 
                new String(' ', nestingCount * INDENT));
        }        
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!hasErrors)
        {
            nestingCount--;
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.Debug("msg" + 
                    new String(' ', nestingCount * INDENT));
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

The exception you are seeing must be thrown by one of the three `new String(' ', nestingCount * INDENT)` calls. That particular `string` constructor call throws when the supplied value is negative. Because `INDENT` is a const, `nestingCount` must have a negative value in that case. `nestingCount` is a thread-static variable. Thread-static variables are always initialized with their default value (0 in this case) and can't be influenced by other threads. Further more, `nestingCount` is never used outside this method.

Because `nestingCount` is thread-static and only used in that method, it is hard to imagine a scenario were `nestingCount` can get negative. Perhaps in the case of an asynchronous (ThreadAbort) exception, but even this I find hard to imagine. Other option is that the thread-static variable is changed by someone else using reflection.

But the big question is: how to solve this?

**Solution:**

There's only one thing I can think of and that is reconfigure log4net in a way that debug information isn't logged. When disallowing debug information, the `string(char, int)` constructor will probably never get called again, which will hide the problem. Not very pretty, but possibly effective. This might work, because the `AbstractObjectFactory` logs using the `log` variable that is initialized as follows:

```
this.log = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
```

You can do this by globally disabling the writing of debug information in log4net, or –when you think this is overkill- by configuring log4net to disable debug info for the type `Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory` (the instance that is actually causes the exception).

Good luck.

Comment: Disabling debug for Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory is an idea that could work. I'll try this and see that the error wont occurr again. The error is definitely weird but quite interesting. Hopefully the base cause will only be limited to this error... Thanks Steven! I'll keep the post updated if anything new comes up.

Comment: @Mattias: I'm very curious if my observations were correct and if disabling debug did in fact solve your problem.

Comment: Hopefully i can give you an answer shortly. This only happens on the production server that hasnt gone live yet. So after next update we'll see.

Comment: @Mattias: Did you have any success with my tips? I'm very curious.

Comment: So far so good. But too early to tell im afraid. Ill keep you posted.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted meanwhile since it was very insightful. So far so good btw.

Comment: Thx for this, i ran into the same problem the other day, but it only occured once in VS's web server during debug mode...

Comment: It's been in production for a few months now, and the error is no where to be seen. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error occur when a database column is mapped to more than one property. A typical case is when a foreign key column is mapped to a property and to collection. A second or third pair of eyes on the config files helps spot these.

One twist with this is that it occurs for all users. Do you have a persistent object that is stored in application state?

Comment: I cant post all code due to confidentiality, but the object that is being located is an internal object with an ISession and an ExceptionHandler as constructor arguments.The error appears when that object is being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occurred after some time during performance testing. It starts fine and after some time this error pops up.

Turns out it was caused by a totally unrelated [ThreadLocal] variable I used in my code. I replaced it with a method parameter and now it works fine.